# reloadData on TableView and perform an UIView animation of LayoutIfNeeded breaks layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, swift3, uiviewanimation

I have a `ViewController` with a `tableView` and a hidden `UIView`.

When the user tap a button I want to:

1. reload the table
2. present the hidden view with animating `Autolayout`

So basically the code is:

```
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        bottomContsraint.update(offset: 50)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.9,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 0.4,
                       options: .curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { }
```

the problem is that my cells also animate when the hiden view show up, I guess it's because of `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

can we call `layoutIfNeeded()` and also `self.tableView.reloadData()` without wired animation on the tableview cells ?

Comment: you could probably call `self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()` first, to prevent it from being run again during animation.

Comment: isn't self.view the UITableView on a UITableViewController? I think you might be referencing the incorrect view property.

Answer (score 0):

layoutIfNeeded cascades to all of a views subviews.  Therefore self.view.layoutIfNeeded() is telling everything in your viewController to relayout.  just call layoutIfNeed on the hidden view